# React - prevstate issues, getting back old value

Tags: reactjs

I have an SVG map with paths, and those paths change colors when I hover over them.
It changes state of specific section, for example my state looks like that:

```
  POL3139: {
    color: '#fbb9c5'
  },
```

I am trying to switch back to the base color after I leave the path.
Here I am changing

```
onHover = (event) => {
event.stopPropagation();
const e = event.target.id
this.setState(prevState => ({
    [e]: {
      ...prevState,
      color: '#650df9'
    },
}));
```

}

It totally works and changes my color to the picked one.
But then I am trying to revert back to the original one.

I tried that by making a base color in the state:

```
  POL3139: {
    color: '#fbb9c5',
    base: '#fbb9c5'
  },
```

and then onMouseLeave:

```
onLeave = (event) => {
event.stopPropagation();
const e = event.target.id;
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [e]: { 
    ...prevState,
    // color: prevState.base - doesn't work
    // color: prevState.[e].base - doesn't work
    // color: [prevState.e.base] - doesn't work
    color: 'pink'
  }
}));
```

}

I was trying many possible solutions but I can't get it to work.
I am still learning react and it might be an easy one but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What does `prevState.base` represent when the updater is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're deconstructing your `prevState` properly.

Here's an example to illustrate how to deconstruct:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    style: {
      color: "black",
      base: "black",
      cursor: "pointer"
    }
  };

  handleMouseEnter = e => {
    const { style } = this.state;
    this.setState({ style: { ...style, color: "red" } });
  };

  handleMouseLeave = e => {
    const { style } = this.state;
    this.setState({ style: { ...style, color: style.base } });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        style={this.state.style}
      >
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In this case `style` is equivalent to your `[e]`.

In particular, look at the deconstructing here:

```
this.setState({ style: { ...style, color: style.base } });
```

There's a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ooqxxx1rrq).

Comment: He's using an `updater` as first function: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: I know, that doesn't really change anything here as far as I'm aware.